# How to stop PHP email script from spamming automated emails?

Tags: php, email, spam

So I have written a PHP webscript that, every time it runs, it sends an email that tells the recipient that a node is down based on response time. Since the node monitors traffic, it needs to be checked constantly. Like every hour or two. The only problem is that when I cron-job it, it sends the same email every single hour. Is there any way to stop this and have it send one email every week, but run every hour to check the node? The mailing portion of my code is below. I am also new to PHP so my form will be very sloppy. (`$lrrt` is the node response time variable)

```
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
{
    //echo $data[$i]["name"]; 
    //echo $data[$i]["lrrt"];
    $lrrt = $data[$i]["lrrt"];
    $name = $data[$i]["name"];

    if ($lrrt >= 120) {
        echo ("the following router is down: {$name}.");
        // The message
        $message = "the following router is down: {$name}. With a response time of: {$lrrt} seconds.";

        $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

        // Send
        mail('Email Adress', 'Routers are down', $message);//When transfering to webserver, change email to true recipient 
    }
}
```

Comment: Save the last time you sent mail in a file. Read the file when starting up, and if it it's been less than a week exit the script.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see how it works out.